# What should be the version of the very first build of a software?

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

As the title explains the question, let's assume that we're using versioning as `major.minor.revision.build`. What should the initial version of a software build be? `0.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` or anything else?

Comment: Who cares? Or put slightly more charitably, why is this important to you?

Comment: That's never a valid answer. "Who cares?" is just against the spirit of SE. Software engineers should care about the conventions

Comment: However, spending time on something which doesn't matter is a bad thing. I don't care whether you start at 0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.1 or something else, just don't spend your time (or even worse, your team's time) worrying about it. Write code instead.

Comment: That's totally off-topic. The question wasn't about time management or even project management. It was about understanding an aspect of the semantic-versioning.

Comment: @iGoodie quite the opposite, semantic versioning describe the format and how each part evolves and what does it mean; it has nothing to say about initial version, because it is completely arbitrary and indeed this has very little impact to the end result, so noone should invest too much time on that as this is useless endeavour.

Comment: When `should` is put in a standard such as an RFC it is taken to have a specific technical meaning, but when `should` is used on SO, moderators get this knee-jerk reaction to call it an "opinion" simple so they can close the question and get their kick-backs for it. Then in the elections they advertise how many questions they closed like it was a good thing, and everyone votes for the moderators who crushed the most good content out of existence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First *build*? 0.0.0.0. Because you are going to build and try your code many times before you reach the point you put a version on it.

But now I'm going to stop nitpicking and assume you mean the first *release*. So - it depends:

- If the first release is a stable one - it should be 1.0.0.###.
- In the more likely case the first release is not a stable one - it should be 0.1.0.###.

The build number is ### because it depends on how you do build numbers - there are several ways to do those buy they tend to be very simple without much room for decisions (like timestamp or incremented number) so just stick with the rules for build number.

The revision/bugfix is 0 - because it's the first release.

Incrementing a major version means you are breaking backward compatibility (at least according to [SemVer](https://semver.org/)), so you usually want to start with 0 - which is special because it means you don't guarantee backward compatibility just yet. And you set the minor version to 1 so that your release won't be 0.0.0.###. This is good for the first releases, because once your software is tried out in the wild and you get some feedback, you may realize some of your design decisions were wrong (or even just "not right enough") and need to introduce some breaking changes - being at major version 0 will allow you to do so without much fuss.

If you do decide to promise backward compatibility from the very first release, you set the major version to 1 and the minor version to 0 because that's the initial minor version for a new major version. You need to have a really good reason to do this though, because that means you'll have to increase a major version on each breaking change, and a month-old project with major version of 23 looks quite alarming.

Comment: This is a great answer and very relevant. While it seems some people do not see the value in versioning, these are probably the same people who do not see much value in a business having proper accounts. In my opinion, versioning is extremely important and should be done properly from the start. When hiring developers, I look at the code they have produced and the conventions they have followed. This tells a lot about the personality and what you can expect to get in return. Good Answer!

Comment: Yeah, but it's only an "opinion" - it "shouldn't" be here on stack exchange ... much.

Answer (score 7):

It is totally arbitrary. The only rule is that version numbers should go up. What you start with and when you bump up different levels may depend on how the team feels, new features, how well everything was tested or what the competition is calling their product. Or the degree of automation involved. Your CI system may be set up to bump up numbers automatically with pushes/check-ins and tagging/labeling/pinning actions.

I would not lose any sleep over it.

Comment: This post has the semantic versioning tag, which means that there are certainly a few more rules than version numbers only going up.

Comment: For anyone reading this answer, just take a look at the other one. I wish the moderator had deleted this answer instead of closing the question :eye-roll:.